# How do I setup a state "manager" that monitors and updates state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently trying to learn React/Redux for work and have been working on a fun side-project - an Incremental Game.

As part of my application I need to setup some kind of component(?) that will watch all state changes (both triggered by user action and by an internal clock "tick") and will update state based on certain thresholds being met.  For the most part this new state will handle conditional component display.

For example, I would expect this state manager to handle things like

```
if (state.clicks >= 10 && state.dragon { 
    // dispatch action to add state.dragonHunter to state
} else if (state.dragon && state.dragonHunter) {
    // dispatch action to add state.dragonBones to state
}
```

so forth and so on.  I imagine this list to be quite long (100+ lines of conditionals) by the time I have added all of the threshold checks.

The thing I can't seem to wrap my mind around is where something like this belongs in my app and how best to set it up in a way that the main entry point of the manager will be called on all state updates, regardless of what is causing the state update (and even if a re-render isn't needed).

Sorry if this is something really basic or if I haven't worded my question very well.  As I said, I am still learning and am mostly self taught.  I will be happy to add clarity where I can if needed.

Comment: why dont you try one of the update lifecycle methods like componentDidUpdate. check this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html for more information

Comment: Redux-saga might be a good fit for what you're doing. This question is too broad to really answer. I suggest trying out one or two approaches on a small scale proof-of-concept and coming back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Update lifecycle method componentDidUpdate. check the state here and the  dispatch.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if (prevState.clicks >= 10 && prevState.dragon { 
    // dispatch action to add state.dragonHunter to state
    } else if (prevState.dragon && prevState.dragonHunter) {
    // dispatch action to add state.dragonBones to state
        }
    }
```

Check this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) for more information aboutlifecycle methods

Answer (score 0):

You must keep a variable `clicks` somewhere. If you want clicks over the lifetime of the app, then you can use asyncstorage or a database for example realm or even upload them to a server.
If your need is just to keep them during the running of a single app instance and you don't have to store them persistently, just store them in a static variable.
Or you could store them as a global state object, using redux. But this may affect performance if you don't wish your app to rerender Everytime the clicks change. 
But if you insist on redux and you don't wish your app to re render when clicks update, you can catch that in `ComponentWillUpdate` 
Then you can use your `if block` as in the number at the point in your app where you wish to know the number of clicks.